# android recyclerview selection tracker dynamic data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've implemented recycler-view with multi selection using the selection-tracker api.

First list of data works properly, but when there's new data with different size then the problem occurs. I've tried to create new tracker on each load but that totally failed to work.

Problem is, when the listdata is refreshed from the api the `ItemKeyProvider.class#getPosition()` returns null.

How can i implement selections tracker with dynamic data avoiding this issue?

```
private void loadPurchaseOrders(ArrayList<PurchaseOrder> newPurchaseOrders) {
        purchaseOrders.clear();
        purchaseOrders.addAll(newPurchaseOrders);

        if (purchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter == null) {
            /* if (workOrderRecyclerAdapter == null) {*/
            purchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter = new PurchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter(getPurchaseOrders(),
                    statusId,
                    purchaseOrder -> getPurchaseOrderDetail(CURRENT_STATE, purchaseOrder));

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            binding.rvPo.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            binding.rvPo.setAdapter(purchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter);

            selectionTrackerBuilder = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>(
                    new Random().toString(),//unique id
                    binding.rvPo,
                    new POItemKeyProvider(getPurchaseOrders()),
                    new POItemDetailsLookup(binding.rvPo),
                    StorageStrategy.createStringStorage());

            selectionTracker = selectionTrackerBuilder.build();

            purchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter.setSelectionTracker(selectionTracker);
        } else {

            purchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

POItemKeyProvider.class

```
private static class POItemKeyProvider extends ItemKeyProvider<String> {

    private final Map<String, Integer> mKeyToPosition;
    private List<PurchaseOrder> mPokemonList;

    POItemKeyProvider(List<PurchaseOrder> pokemonList) {
        super(SCOPE_CACHED);
        mPokemonList = pokemonList;

        mKeyToPosition = new HashMap<>(mPokemonList.size());
        int i = 0;
        for (PurchaseOrder pokemon : pokemonList) {
            mKeyToPosition.put(pokemon.getOrderNo(), i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getKey(int i) {
        return mPokemonList.get(i).getOrderNo();// directly from position to key
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(@NonNull String s) {
        return mKeyToPosition.get(s);
    }
}
```

POItemDetailsLookup.class

```
private static class POItemDetailsLookup extends ItemDetailsLookup<String> {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

        POItemDetailsLookup(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            this.mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ItemDetails<String> getItemDetails(@NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View view = mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            if (view != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view);
//                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (viewHolder instanceof PurchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder) {
                    return ((PurchaseOrderRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getItemDetails(motionEvent);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation should work with dynamic data:

https://github.com/ExpensiveBelly/RecyclerViewSelection

Because of this:

```
override fun submitList(list: List<T>?) {
        super.submitList(list)
        tracker.deselectIfItemsNotFound(currentList)
    }
```